# Reference the activity hosting a control

Tags: android

In my Android app I create a custom WebView class and include this within the xml layout file. The class also overrides some methods. Within one of these methods, I would like to reference the activity that is hosting the WebView control. Is there a way to reference the activity without having to store a static reference to it somewhere?

Comment: pass the context of calling activity as a parameter to the method. so every time that method gets called, it would require the calling activity's context to be passed as parameter.

Comment: when you create a View you already pass a context to it, save it.